# JavaScript catch Block with Wrong Context

Tags: javascript, pyqt, try-catch, qtwebkit

I've got the following code:

```
try {
    ...

    try {
        // This is *never* called
        alert('TRY');
    } catch (e) {
        // But this *is* called
        alert('CATCH');
    }

} catch (e2) {
    ...
}
```

The problem is, the alert from the inner `catch` block is executed but *not* the one from the inner `try`.

Is this possible at all per specification or does anyone have an idea what is happening here ?
Can an exception from e.g. asynchronous code run into the context of another catch block ?

Note this is real code I put in there, no omissions in the inner `try` / `catch` !
Some asynchronous code may be run before entering the block.

This is from code taken from a web app running in WebKit / QtWebKit from PyQt 4.9.0 and Qt 4.8.0.

---

Ok, so here some more code before the inner try/catch (where the first ellipsis is):

```
DoSomething(function () {
    var updatePromises = [];
    var p;

    for (...) {
        p = new Promise();
        updatePromises.push(p);

        // Run asynchronous code to fulfill promise.
        // Calls are chained using an array and a "setTimeout()" mechanism.
        tasks.chain(function (promise) { ... }, this, p);
    }

    (function () {
         ...
    }).future().apply(this, updatePromises);
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Where is the code located that throws?

Comment: Those ellipses will cause the code to fail to be parsed... What did you omit?

Comment: I don't think it would help to put more code in there where the ellipses are. But FYI, the first block calls a function with a callback that is then run and contains various operations with promises using MooTools and ShiftSpace's promises implementation (https://github.com/ShiftSpace/promises).

Comment: The question is, can there be any (allowed per specs) situation where code outside that inner `try`/`catch` can branch *into* that inner `catch` block ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ES5 specification](http://es5.github.com/#x12.14) says the following (emphasis added):

> The try statement encloses a block of code in which an exceptional
> condition can occur, such as a runtime error or a throw statement. The
> catch clause provides the exception-handling code.
>
> ...
>
> The production *TryStatement* : `try` *Block Catch* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. **Let *B* be the result of evaluating *Block***.
> 2. If *B*.type is not throw, return *B*.
> 3. Return the result of evaluating *Catch* with parameter *B*.

My understanding of that is that, according to the spec, there is no way a catch block can be executed without first evaluating the try block.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to be a bug somewhere in the software stack and the particular code invoked with all the side effects. Gotta live with it and work around...

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the answer is no, based on the [mozilla reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch).  I recommend you log each time a block is entered and exited, and see if there is any weird stuff going on that you missed.  Maybe use `debugger;` too.

Or try this perhaps:

```
var foo = false;
try {
    try {
        foo = true;
        throw true;
    } catch (e) {
        if(foo) {
            alert('CATCH');
        } else {
            alert('HUH?');
        }
    }
} catch (e2) {
    alert('CATCH2');
}
```

Comment: Note that conditional catch clauses are non-standard. I'm pretty sure they're not supported by WebKit (which is what the OPs app runs in).